# superClass at eclipse IDE plugin Development

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, ide

I'm developing an eclipse IDE, I faced this plugin xml point.

```
<option category="elf.compiler.general"
       id="elf.compiler.dialect.std.cpp"
       name="C++ language standard"                        
       superClass="gnu.cpp.compiler.option.dialect.std"/>
```

As I understand this plugin point is driven from "gnu.cpp.compiler.option.dialect.std", right?

this class provide c++ compiler versions.

my question is how to see what this class include exactly? and how to add more option to my IDE while still using this class? (lets assume this class have A,B,C options, I want to add D option, I can define my plugin with A,B,C,D options without using dialect.std class but I want to know if I can use Superclass and add new options).

Thanks

Comment: That is just a part of an extension point, show us the whole extension point starting with the `<extension` element.

Comment: its so long, something like this:
 

`<extension id="custom.buildDefinitions"
               name="CustomELF"
               point="org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.buildDefinitions">

<optionCategory id="elf.compiler.general"
                                name="General"/>

<option category="elf.compiler.general"
       id="elf.compiler.dialect.std.cpp"
       name="C++ language standard"                        
       superClass="gnu.cpp.compiler.option.dialect.std"/> `

Comment: See documentation in the help or here: https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_cdt_managedbuilder_core_buildDefinitions.html